# How to save HABTM relationship via _ids parameter

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a project with a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship between users and projects. I'm trying to create a project using checkboxes on the project form to select users, but it's failing at the save stage with an error `Users is invalid`.

My user model is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects

  devise :database_authenticatable,
    :recoverable,
    :rememberable,
    :trackable,
    :lockable,
    :timeoutable

  validates :username,
    presence: true,
    length: { minimum: USER_NAME_MIN_LENGTH,
              maximum: USER_NAME_MAX_LENGTH },
    allow_blank: false,
    allow_nil: false,
    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

  validates_format_of :email,
    with: Devise.email_regexp,
    if: :email_changed?

  validates_presence_of :password,
    on: :create

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_length_of :password,
     within: Devise.password_length
  validates_presence_of :role
```

My project model is:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  validates :name,
    uniqueness: true,
    presence: true,
    length: {within: 1..PROJECT_NAME_MAX_LENGTH}

  validates :base_year,
    presence: true,
    numericality:
       {only_integer: true,
       greater_than_or_equal_to: BASE_YEAR_MIN,
       less_than_or_equal_to: BASE_YEAR_MAX}

  validates :client, length: {maximum: CLIENT_NAME_MAX_LENGTH}

  validates :work_order, length: {maximum: WORK_ORDER_MAX_LENGTH}
end
```

My form view (HAML) is:

```
= form_for(project) do |f|
  - if project.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2
        = pluralize(project.errors.count, "error")
        prevented this project being saved:
      %ul
        - project.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
          %li= message
  %table
    %tr.field
      %td= f.label :name
      %td= f.text_field :name
    %tr.field
      %td= f.label :base_year
      %td= f.number_field :base_year
    %tr.field
      %td= f.label :work_order
      %td= f.text_field :work_order
    %tr.field
      %td= f.label :client
      %td= f.text_field :client
    %tr.field
      %td= f.label :active
      %td= f.check_box :active
  %h2 Users
  - User.all.each do |user|
    %td= check_box_tag 'project[user_ids][]', user.id,     @project.users.include?(user)
    %td= user.username
  .actions
    = f.submit 'Save'
```

I have put some debugging print statements into the projects controller, to see where it's going wrong. The create section of that controller is:

```
def create
  @project = Project.new(project_params)
  @project.users.each do |user|
    puts "=== User: #{user.username}"
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    if @project.save then
      # Print statement for debugging
      puts '=== Save success'
      on_save_success(format,
                      Project,
                      @project,
                      notice: 'Project was successfully created.')
    else
      # Print statement for debugging
      puts '=== Save fail'
      on_save_fail(format, @project.errors)
    end
  end
end
```

The line `@project = Project.new(project_params)` appears to be succeeding, and the subsequent block correctly displays all of the users I've checked on the form (there's only one, actually), but the save is failing. The console output is:

```
Started POST "/projects" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-25 16:11:18 +0000
Processing by ProjectsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"S4Kawr8r7nVlpZdimAcvkER0lB70UQZ1zOoo8/82g4g=", "project"=>{"name"=>"Test", "base_year"=>"2000", "work_order"=>"", "client"=>"", "active"=>"0", "user_ids"=>["1"]}, "commit"=>"Save"}                                         
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]                                        
=== User: alice                                                                                                                         
    (0.0ms)  begin transaction                                                                                                           
  User Exists (0.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE (LOWER("users"."username") = LOWER('alice') AND "users"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1  
  Project Exists (0.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "projects"  WHERE "projects"."name" = 'Test' LIMIT 1                                    
    (1.0ms)  rollback transaction                                                                                                        
=== Save fail
```

I can't see what it objects to about users -- there's no validation on them. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
I can't work out how to add the debugger, so I just put in the @project.valid and @project_errors as debugging print statements:

```
@project = Project.new(project_params)
puts "=== Project is #{@project.valid? ? "" : "not "} valid"
puts "=== Errors:"
puts @project.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
```

The result is:

```
Started POST "/projects" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-29 16:06:13 +0000
Processing by ProjectsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"WAIMP+Z/g0bKFWhh/DUcroMooJoPTsUx3A9y6XZCJWk=", "project"=>{"name"=>"Test", "base_year"=>"2000", "work_order"=>"", "client"=>"", "active"=>"1", "user_ids"=>["1"]}, "commit"=>"Save"}
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE (LOWER("users"."username") = LOWER('alice') AND "users"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
  Project Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "projects"  WHERE "projects"."name" = 'Test' LIMIT 1
=== Project is not  valid
=== Errors:
Users is invalid
  (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE (LOWER("users"."username") = LOWER('alice') AND "users"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1

  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "projects"  WHERE "projects"."name" = 'Test' LIMIT 1
  (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
=== Save fail
```

Comment: I would add debugger or binding.pry and call @project.valid? and @project.errors.

Comment: provide, please, errors for not saving object

Comment: As above, @project.valid? and puts @project.errors.full_messages.to_sentence

Comment: Help on adding the debugger would be useful, but for the moment I've done as requested as an edit in the original query. Unfortunately, I don't think it adds much.

Comment: Playing around in the rails console, I wonder whether @project is trying to validate the user? If I run `valid?` on the user it fails because the password is too short. The password isn't too short, but rails can't know that because the plaintext isn't stored (on User create and update it would have the plaintext, of course). Do I need to prevent project save validating the associated users (which I know will be valid), and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed the problem is that Rails is trying to validate the user entries, even though that validation isn't needed and fails because I validate on the length of the plaintext password, which doesn't exist when I save a project. I'm therefore closing this question, and posting [a new question that is more specific to the issue as I now understand it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35158044/prevent-habtm-validation).

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same issues and i resolved it by following 2 changes

- Add <%= hidden_field_tag "project[user_ids][]", nil %> line before your check_box_tag.
- Make sure your existing users are valid, if you will add invalid user then it will give you the "Users are invalid"  error.

Answer (score 0):

Add below hidden tag before check_box_tag.

```
`<%= hidden_field_tag("project[user_ids][]", nil) %>`
```

The hidden_field_tag allows the user to uncheck all the boxes and successfully remove all the associations.

Or you can use collection_check_boxes

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:user_ids, User.all, :id, :username) do |b| %>
  <%= b.check_box %> <%= b.label %>
<% end %>
```