# Prevent HABTM validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a project where a `User` `has_and_belongs_to_many` projects, and a `Project` `has_and_belongs_to_many` users. When I create a new project, I want to be able to associate it with one or more users, which I'm doing by passing an array of `user_ids` amongst the project creation parameters.

The creation is working fine, but I can't save the newly created project because the `User`s fail validation (because I'm validating on password length with `validates_length_of :password, within: Devise.password_length`, and the plaintext of the password isn't saved with the user.

Clearly, I don't need `Project#save` to validate the `User`s (beyond presence of the user IDs in the join table), because the user already exists and is validated, and as far as I can tell I'm not asking for it, so how can I stop it happening?

Comment: Try `@project.save!(validate: false)` in the `projects_controller#create` action.

Comment: Won't that also stop it validating the Project entry? I need that validation to occur, in order to maintain database consistency.